# Strange Wordpress issue just in Firefox

Tags: wordpress, firefox, header, genesis

I have a strange issue happening **just in Firefox** that disappear when I resize the browser page.

The issue is **on the header**, normally, on a Desktop mode, the logo it's in the center with two menu, one on the left and one on the right. In Firefox I see just the logo on the left and the menu all on the right part.

I tried to explore the code and see where this issue is coming from but I can't find any solution. Can someone help me please?

https://ruggerocarrara.com

Thank you so much!

Comment: A bit late for me so I stop for now. But I saw: My current line to further look into is the behavior of the menu in responsive. The tag on the menus read "genesis". Don't know about it but I noticed that making the view smaller lets the menu switch from left to right on correct behavior. Possibly something in firefox does not have the information of the width at the time it is evaluated for first render by the genesis menu.

Comment: Hey Uwe, I found the error, was an option in the plugin WP Rocket called "Optimize CSS delivery eliminates render-blocking CSS on your website for faster perceived load time.". 

It seems useful from the Page Speed tests and I would like to use it. There is also a space to place the CSS to exclude from this process but I just don't understand this information "Use (.*).css wildcards to exclude all CSS files located at a specific path.". 

Last thing, how can I know what CSS was the one that create the issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Funny. I was suspecting WP Rocket could influence the problem when I saw it in the source of the page :-). I will have to use that shortly on a website I help out so i am even more curious on the problem. Hope I will have time to look into the issue today.

Comment: But I don't have a reproducing sample :-). Do you happen to have a minimum sample at hand? As your page works now :-).

Comment: No worries mate, you've been too kind. I just avoid that option for now. Thank you so much!